# Encode and Decode in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using Encoding and decoding :

For Encoding:

```
private string EncodeServerName(string ServerName)
    {
      byte[] NameEncodein = new byte[ServerName.Length];
      NameEncodein = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ServerName);
      string EcodedName = Convert.ToBase64String(NameEncodein);
      return EcodedName;
    }
```

and Decoding:

```
     public string DecoAndGetServerName(string Servername)
     {
         System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
         System.Text.Decoder strDecoder = encoder.GetDecoder();
         byte[] to_DecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(Servername);
         int charCount = strDecoder.GetCharCount(to_DecodeByte, 0, to_DecodeByte.Length);
         char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
         strDecoder.GetChars(to_DecodeByte, 0, to_DecodeByte.Length, decoded_char,0);
         string Name = new string(decoded_char);

         return Name;
     }
```

I am sending ServerName:`DEV-SQL1\SQL2008`

It is encoded:`REVWLVNRTDFcU1FMMjAwOA==`

Again i want to decode but getting Exception:in line:

`byte[] to_DecodeByte = Convert.FromBase64String(Servername);`

Exception IS:

`The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character,

more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.`

How to solve this issue.

Please Help Me

Comment: Log/Show your encoded string right after encode and right before decode. Make sure it is _exactly_ the same.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your code seems way too complex :-), here is one that works:

```
public static string EncodeServerName(string serverName)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serverName));
}

public static string DecodeServerName(string encodedServername)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedServername));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the same code works for me, which you written in `DecoAndGetServerName()`.

the thing is, you need to pass `ENCODED STRING` to your `DecoAndGetServerName()` function,

which might be encoded like :

```
string Servername=Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("serverName"));
```

That's why you got that Error  `The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character,...`.